# ValueAnimator Lint Error: This animation should be started with #start() [Recycle]

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, animator

I'm creating ValueAnimator in `init()` method like this:

```
internal var animator: ValueAnimator? = null

@CallSuper
open fun init() {
    animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(-1F, 2F)
    animator?.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION
    animator?.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    animator?.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
    animator?.repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
    animator?.addUpdateListener(this)
}
```

I'm starting/stopping it depending on the visibility of the view:

```
override fun onVisibilityChanged(changedView: View, visibility: Int) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility)
    when (visibility) {
        VISIBLE -> animator?.start()
        INVISIBLE, GONE -> animator?.cancel()
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following Lint error:

> Error: This animation should be started with #start() [Recycle]
> animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(-1F, 2F)
> ~~~~~~~
>
> Explanation for issues of type "Recycle":    Many resources, such
> as TypedArrays, VelocityTrackers, etc., should be    recycled (with a
> recycle() call) after use. This lint check looks for    missing
> recycle() calls.

There's no `recycle()` method for `ValueAnimator`. I tried to create a new animator each time I need to start it, but I couldn't find a way to provide needed properties without getting this Lint error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Let me guess, you might be having this issue when your view is gone/invisible even before it was visible. meaning you can't cancel() animation if it's not running. Same thing goes for visibility. Animations should be reentrant and consistent. I'd recommend going through this article once: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/motional-intelligence-build-smarter-animations-821af4d5f8c0

Comment: Thanks for the article. I don't have any issues with animation when running the app, it works just fine. The problem is with Lint giving this error and I'm not sure how to fix it - how to recycle animator properly in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the lint error u can create a value animator instance every time when the view is visible like this:-

```
fun createAndStartAnim() {
     animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(-1F, 2F).apply {
             duration = ANIMATION_DURATION
             interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
             repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
             repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
             addUpdateListener(this@YourUpdateListener)
             start() // this removes the lint error
     }
}
```

We need to cancel by :-

```
fun cancelAndNullifyAnim() {
    animator?.cancel()
    animator = null
}
```

Now on visibility change:-

```
when (visibility) {
        VISIBLE -> createAndStartAnim()
        INVISIBLE, GONE -> cancelAndNullifyAnim()
}
```

> The lint error should be gone if we **start** the value anim before accessing any other recyclable properties of it.